# Libraries to create this type of chart?

Tags: graph, charts, google-visualization

The website I'm building will have content in various languages. I'm looking for a nice way to present the "langages" data, for those interested.

I really like this visualisation : http://www.climateinstitute.org.au/lcci

[image]

It is basically a series of sparklines, drawn at decreasing heights. I would use it, for instance, to display the overall number of posts in a language (→ height of the sparkline), and the evolution of this number (→ the sparkline itself).

Is there a chart drawing library that could do something like that ? I don't need it to be "clickable" / zoomable, a static image would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the SparkLine charts provided in FusionWidgets XT - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#spark-charts